# How do get request.user in django models.py or forms.py. Is it possible?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to filter a ForeignKey object. If possible, I want to do some checks in Django models.py and need to get the logged-in user, like request.user as it is used in views.py.

I want to append the username to this return statement if the condition is met like this below:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        item_user = self.item_name + ' - ' + self.created_by
        if request.user in item_user:
            return item_user
        else:
            return self.item_name
```

Comment: You *don't*. Models should be *request unaware*. In fact it is not even said that modifications happen through the web endpoint, management commands for example do not run with a *Django* user.

Comment: Thanks for helping to stop focusing on impossible ways to archive it. It helped me start finding another way and finally got the solution. I will post it here if anyone needs it. Thanks again @WillemVanOnsem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution and I am posting it here for anyone who needs it. From the comment of @willemVanOnsem I focused on solving it in another way instead of doing it in the model. Here is how I solve it:
I wanted to pass the username of the person who created a store item so that I can display just the items they created when selecting these objects from another model:
So I used forms to filter and display the needed objects.

Below are the models:

ModelOne:

```
class ModelOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    line_one = models.ForeignKey(Store, blank=True, null=True, related_name='line_one')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True, null=True)
```

ModelTwo:

```
class ModelTwo(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=15, default='', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Below is the form with the needed filter:

```
class FormOne(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelOne
        fields = [
                'name',
                'phone_number',
                'line_one'
                ]

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FormOne, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['line_one'].queryset = ModelTwo.objects.filter(created_by = user)
```

Now I pass the username through the view:

```
def create(request):
    user = request.user
    form = FormOne(user, request.POST or None)
    queryset = ModelOne.objects.all()
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    context = {
        "form": form,
        "queryset": queryset,
    }
    return render(request, "entry.html", context)
```